# $S = \{(x,y,z) : F(x,y,z) = 0\}$ using implicit function theorem to reach $dS = \sqrt{1 + f_{x}^{2} + f_{y}^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

$S = \{(x,y,z) : F(x,y,z) = 0\}$

$F \in  C^{1}$

$F_{z} \neq 0$

In the solution using the implicit function theorem they somehow reach  $dS = \sqrt{1 + f_{x}^{2} + f_{y}^{2}}$ . and this is my question.

They do not explain too much how, something about plane colliding with the graph, but I fail to see the true meaning of that and how we reach the above equation from it. 
I only know that the tangent plane in a point in this scenario should be

$z-z_{0} = f'_{x}(x_{0},y_0) (x-x_{0}) + f'_{y}(x_{0},y_0) (y-y_{0}) $

Don't know what to do from here to get to the $dS$ equation.

I do not think the rest of the question is necessary because I only need to know how to reach the dS equation above from the given data to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have $F$ and you want to determine $\sqrt{1 + f_{x}^{2} + f_{y}^{2}}$.

By differentiating with respect to $x$ and to $y$ the implicit equation $F(x,y,z)=0$ we obtain, respectively, 
$$F_x+F_z \cdot f_x=0\;,\; F_y+F_z \cdot f_y=0\implies
f_x=-\frac{F_x}{F_z}\;,\; f_y=-\frac{F_y}{F_z},$$
where $z=f(x,y)$. Hence
$$\sqrt{1 + f_{x}^{2} + f_{y}^{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{F_x^2+F_y^2+ F_z^2}}{|F_z|}.$$

Comment: @user3575645 Did I annswer to your question?

Comment: Thanks, while you reached the final solution like the task required, I just need to know how to reach $\sqrt{1 + f_{x}^{2} + f_{y}^{2}}$, or in short, why  

$dS = \sqrt{1 + f_{x}^{2} + f_{y}^{2}}$

Comment: It follows from the definition of surface integral: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_integral#Surface_integrals_of_scalar_fields

Comment: Oh just what I was looking for, thanks!